# ValueError: Cannot infer Tensor's rank: Tensor("fifo_queue_Dequeue:0", dtype=float32)

Tags: python-2.7, queue, training-data, tensorflow

I am trying to load batches of images each of different size(to be specific they are from pascal voc dataset). source_images.npy file contains images of different heights, widths but same channels. What i am doing wrong? Are there any other methods to send images of different sizes?

This is my Code:

```
def feed(images, im, epochs=None):
    epochs_elapsed = 0
    while epochs is None or epochs_elapsed < epochs:
        for i in range(len(images)):
            yield {im: images[i]}
        epochs_elapsed += 1


def tf_ops(images, capacity=200):
    im = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    queue = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity, [tf.float32])
    enqueue_op = queue.enqueue(im)
    fqr = FeedingQueueRunner(queue, [enqueue_op],
                             feed_fns=[feed(images,im).next()])
    tf.train.add_queue_runner(fqr)
    return queue.dequeue()

source_images = np.load('source_images.npy')
source_images=source_images.tolist()
source_im= tf_ops(source_images)
source_im_batch = tf.train.batch([source_im],batch_size=128,capacity=200, dynamic_pad=True)
```

Error:

```
source_im_batch = tf.train.batch([source_im], batch_size=128,capacity=200, dynamic_pad=True)
File "/home/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 872, in batch
name=name)
File "/home/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 655, in _batch
shapes = _shapes([tensor_list], shapes, enqueue_many)
File "/home/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 598, in _shapes
raise ValueError("Cannot infer Tensor's rank: %s" % tl[i])
ValueError: Cannot infer Tensor's rank: Tensor("fifo_queue_Dequeue:0", dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Solved this problem by using PaddingFiFOQueue Thanks! :)

Comment: can you add the solution in the answer section for community benefit. Thanks!